# Overall efficiency of fprintf and stdout

Tags: c

I have a program that regularly writes to stdout. Something like this:

```
fprintf(stdout, ...);
fprintf(stdout, ...);
fprintf(stdout, ...);
```

This makes the program easy to read but I'm curious to know how efficient is it compared to concatenating strings to some char[] and then calling a single fprintf(stdout...) on that char[]. By efficiency, I'm referring to processing efficiency.

Comment: How long would the string become? Would you need to `malloc()` (and `free()`)? Does the `...` include too many conversion specifiers and their corresponding values? ???

Comment: There is no dynamic alloc. The strings are typically using two or three format specifiers.

Comment: `fprintf()` is slow because it has to parse the format string, use `fwrite()` is probably the fastest (no parsing, no memory handling and no `strlen()` required). And set the buffer to full buffer mode.

Comment: Is your program too slow? If not, do not bother about this things.

Comment: The program is not particularly slow but it reports status updates at regular intervals and I would like to minimize any resource overheads that the reporting may have.

Comment: @OS2 I would consider not bother about performance till it is a problem.

Comment: Thanks, in a larger program I wouldn't bother about it :)

Comment: In a similar experiment I wrote the same program as a shell script that invoked grep, awk and sed to accomplish the same tasks of parsing the very same input and then reporting it. The overall performance of that script was a lot worse with very high load on cpu cycles. I feel it's worth some effort in getting the program to perform as efficiently as possible.

Answer (score 0):

The whole of `stdio.h` is notoriously slow, as are writes to the screen or files in general. What makes `stdio.h` particularly bad, is that it's a cumbersome wrapper around the underlying OS API. `printf`/`scanf`-like functions have an horrible interface forcing them to deal with both format string parsing and variable argument lists, before they can even pass along the data to the function doing the actual work.

Minimizing those `fprintf` calls into a single one will almost definitely improve performance. But then that depends on how you "concatenate strings", if it is done with `sprintf`, then you have only moved all the calling/parsing overhead from one icky stdio.h function to another.

The only reason you would ever use `stdio.h` is if you need to create very portable console and file I/O code. Otherwise, you'd call the OS API directly.

That being said, you should only manually optimize code when there is a need for it. If the program runs "fast enough" without any known bottlenecks, then leave it be and strive to write as readable code as possible.

Comment: `stdio.h` is not slow, `fwrite()` is probably faster than the Linux `write()` because `fwrite()` uses buffering, if the buffer is set correctly. `printf()` and `scanf()` families take a long time because of format parsing-

Comment: We all learnt that outputting to a terminal/vdu is slow. The alternative would be to call multiple sprintf to concat the string. Then output the final output to the screen. Though using sprintf is synatacticaly messier because you have to carry the main string around. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: `multiple sprintf to concat the string` using sprintf the string operaions is not the most efficient way

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 That's a Linux-specific problem though. There's lots of questionable APIs in Linux, particularly the old bad ones it has inherited from Unix.

Comment: If I have to output different types (char[], float, int) then I have to use format specifiers. The word "terminal" is loosely used here to denote the vdu. I'm not concerned with the efficiency of the terminal program but am just interested in getting the output to the display. sprintf is an alternative way to concat different strings but consensus is that it's not much better than repeated calls to fprintf. @P__J__ care to elaborate on a more efficient method?

Comment: @OS2 Rolling out the conversion manually or use `strtol` family of functions.

Comment: Ok in that case rolling a custom print method.

Comment: @Lundin No, `printf()` has to do a lot of format parsing and there is nothing Linux can do about it and this is the same on any other OS as well. `write()` is a syscall, syscalls are slower and `write()` is simple, it does not use buffering. `fwrite()` requires some sort of `write()` to work. Not seeing what there is questionable about it. I also do not see how any other system can create a API which is a lot faster than `fwrite()` (with the correct buffering) on Linux, without weaker security. So, not a Linux specific problem.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Consider an embedded system where `fprintf(stdout,...` boils down to serial bus output. Such output would only need a caller allocated buffer to work, nothing else. But when you toss the data to `fprintf`, it needs to store the result of the format parsing in some temporary internal buffer, which adds nothing but bloat. In the simplest of systems with all bloat removed, all that's needed is some API like `size_t serial_write (const char* uint8_t data, size_t size);`, where all formatting is already done and present in the called-allocated buffer.

Comment: @Lundin This systems do not have a MMU, they do not need to copy data around and they do not have syscalls. That is why is said "without weaker security", because you lose security features when you do not have a MMU. On linux when a program writes to the wrong memory location, nothing happens to other programs but on a µC it causes UB for the whole system. Your `serial_write` looks a lot like `write()`, except for the error handling and the fd.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 Upper end MCUs might very well have a MMU, look at various PowerPC etc. You can set up virtual memory and get exceptions when trying to access wrong memory. I don't see what that has to do with this example though.

Comment: @Lundin If you have and use a MMU, then you need syscalls and you need to copy data and there you are not a lot faster than Linux. The point is you say it is a Linux specific problem, but no it is a "problem" as soon as you use a system which uses a MMU, it is the same on Windows. My distinction was not really clear, the difference should be systems which use a MMU and systems that don't, not embedded vs not embedded, since a lot of embeded systems have a MMU and AFAIK AmigaOS didn't use one.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 No, you don't, there's no system to call. I've written bare metal PowerPC programs where I wrote the MMU and virtual memory setup myself. Which in turn had very little to do with shovelling data from the application onto a serial bus.

Comment: @Lundin A Program that runs inside a MMU can not write data to other pages it does not own nor can it access the register needed send data with an UART. Otherwise the MMU would be useless.

Comment: @12431234123412341234123 A MMU maps memory, hence the name. It doesn't run anything, it just tells the CPU which addresses that are valid. What it allows depends on how you configure it and how advanced it is. There's low end MMUs that you just tell "here's my RAM, here's my flash, off you go" and it doesn't use virtual addresses nor block anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 bottlenecks i know of that can cause slow performance when you call `fprintf(stdout,....)`:

- Format parsing
- Buffering
- Your Terminal or other `stdout` device

To avoid the format parsing, you could write using `fwrite()`, but then you have to create the output string in a other way and if this is faster is questionable.

Normally, `stdout` uses a line buffer, this means that the data has to be checked for `\n` characters and, assuming you running on a OS, for every line a syscall is used. Syscalls are relatively slow compared to normal function calls. Setting the buffer to full buffering with [`setvbuf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/setvbuf/) and
`_IOFBF` is probably the fastest buffer method. Use `BUFSIZ` or try different buffer sizes and benchmark them to find the best value.

When your terminal is slow, then there is nothing you can do about in your program. You could write to a file which can be faster or use a faster terminal. AFAIK [Alacritty](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty) is probably the fastest terminal on Linux.